# Reaching new state in React (Hooks)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a small Tic tac toe game, everything is fine except I am struggling on finding where to put finish function in the code. Let me show you;

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { isGameOver } from "../Helper/helper";
import Square from "./Square";

const Board: React.FC = () => {
  const [squares, setSquares] = useState(new Array(9).fill(""));
  const [activePlayer, setActivePlayer] = useState("Player 1");
  const [winner, setWinner] = useState<any>();

  const clickSquare = (id: number): void => {
    if (!squares[id]) {
      if (activePlayer === "Player 1") {
        setActivePlayer("Player 2");
      } else {
        setActivePlayer("Player 1");
      }
    }
    setSquares((prevSquares) => {
      return prevSquares.map((square, i) => {
        if (i === id && !square) {
          square = activePlayer === "Player 1" ? "X" : "O";
        }
        return square;
      });
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="board">
      <div className="game-field">
        {squares.map((square, i) => {
          return (
            <Square clickSquare={clickSquare} square={square} key={i} i={i} />
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <p
        style={{
          marginRight: activePlayer === "Player 1" ? "250px" : "-250px",
        }}
      >
        {activePlayer + "'s turn"}
      </p>
      <p> </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Board;
```

This is basically the whole game and I have a finishing function in another file like this;

```
export const isGameOver = (squares: String[]) => {
  const won = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < won.length; i++) {
    const [x, y, z] = won[i];
    if (squares[x] && squares[x] === squares[y] && squares[y] === squares[z]) {
      return squares[x];
    }
  }
  return null;
};
```

The finishing function also working fine, but since useState is working asynchoronously and I know that, I'm struggling where to put it. If I put inside of the click function it is not able to react new state, only the state just before. If I put outside with just If statement, it says too many renders cause I'm setting the winner etc.. I mean I want to also stop the game, stop clicking events etc.. Couldn't find a way how to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need `useEffect`. Basically, check if the game is over, everytime a square is clicked:

```
useEffect(() => {
 if(squares){
   if(isGameOver(squares)){
     setSquares(null)
     /* Do other stuff */
   }
 }
}, [squares])
```

By passing `squares` to the dependency array, you tell react that you want this `useEffect` to be run everytime `squares` state variable changes. You can [read more](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) here

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think about useEffect.. Thank you, much appreciated.

Comment: No problem, happy coding